# Install Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on Oracle Linux Server

Tags: command-line, ssl, oracle-linux, letsencrypt, oracle-vm-server

I am trying to install a Let's Encrypt certificate on a Oracle Linux Server 7.6. Since the server does not have a public IP, I had to validate via DNS.I followed the instructions here https://github.com/joohoi/acme-dns-certbot-joohoi and the validation worked and I got the certificate. How do I now install the certificate?

I followed instructions online and moved the certificate to etc/ssl/certs and deleted the old certificate. After restarting the machine however the website does not work and I get an error site cannot be reached.

I can interact with the server only via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should be comparable to CentOS 7.6. The path `etc/ssl/certs` is simply a symbolic link to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`. The certificate is divided into two parts, the first which you have already mentioned is the *.crt file which contains the public key and shall be placed in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` which is in my case `certificate.crt`, while the other part is the private key, and shall be placed in `/etc/pki/tls/private/`, usually has *.key extension, in my case `private.key`.

In case you are using Apache web server, here is a working example of my `redmine.conf`, it should be enough to guide you thru:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias 192.0.2.37

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_bundle.crt

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/redmine/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I almost forgot to mention - which might solve your problem - is that you need to make sure that you have firewall rules in place, and permanent ones as follows:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http --add-service=https --zone=public
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also, make sure you have SeLinux disabled in case you have not changed its rules for your web service.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. The main thing that I was missing was modifying the request_tracker.conf to point to the new SSL certificate.

Comment: What is the purpose of ServerAlias with an IP address? If there is an HTTPS access with the IP as hostname in the URL the certificate will not match (as it does not have the IP address in it, just the hostname)

Comment: Completely disabling Selinux may have far reaching consequences...

Comment: ServerAlias is not necessary in this case, still you can use it regardless of the certificate, you can bypass it on the browser

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:

Connect to the server:

```
root@138.197.165.222's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64)

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

System information as of Tue Jun 18 03:51:19 UTC 2019

System load: 0.01 Processes: 86
Usage of /: 16.9% of 19.21GB Users logged in: 0
Memory usage: 25% IP address for eth0: 138.197.165.222
Swap usage: 0%

Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Tue Jun 18 01:45:08 2019 from 168.243.226.113
```

Add the repository:

```
root@jaimemontoya:~# add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
 This is the PPA for packages prepared by Debian Let's Encrypt Team and backported for Ubuntu(s).
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp_u4kdj9u/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp_u4kdj9u/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 8C47BE8E75BCA694: public key "Launchpad PPA for certbot" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: imported: 1
OK
```

Update the package list to pick up the new repository's package information

```
root@jaimemontoya:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Install Certbot from the new repository with apt-get:

```
root@jaimemontoya:~# apt-get install python-certbot-apache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
 linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
 augeas-lenses certbot libaugeas0 python3-acme python3-augeas python3-certbot
 python3-certbot-apache python3-configargparse python3-future python3-icu
 python3-josepy python3-mock python3-ndg-httpsclient python3-parsedatetime
 python3-pbr python3-requests-toolbelt python3-rfc3339 python3-tz
 python3-zope.component python3-zope.event python3-zope.hookable
Suggested packages:
 augeas-doc python3-certbot-nginx python-certbot-doc augeas-tools
 python-acme-doc python-certbot-apache-doc python-future-doc python-mock-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 augeas-lenses certbot libaugeas0 python-certbot-apache python3-acme
 python3-augeas python3-certbot python3-certbot-apache python3-configargparse
 python3-future python3-icu python3-josepy python3-mock
 python3-ndg-httpsclient python3-parsedatetime python3-pbr
 python3-requests-toolbelt python3-rfc3339 python3-tz python3-zope.component
 python3-zope.event python3-zope.hookable
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,654 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,585 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 augeas-lenses all 1.10.1-2 [300 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-josepy all 1.1.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [27.8 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-pbr all 3.1.1-3ubuntu3 [53.8 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python3-mock all 2.0.0-3 [47.5 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-tz all 2018.3-2 [25.1 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-rfc3339 all 1.0-4 [6,356 B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python3-ndg-httpsclient all 0.4.4-1 [23.5 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python3-configargparse all 0.11.0-1 [22.4 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python3-zope.event all 4.2.0-1 [7,402 B]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libaugeas0 amd64 1.10.1-2 [159 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-icu amd64 1.9.8-0ubuntu1 [173 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-requests-toolbelt all 0.8.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [38.3 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-acme all 0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [49.8 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-future all 0.15.2-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3 [333 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-parsedatetime all 2.4-3+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3 [32.4 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-zope.hookable amd64 4.0.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [9,532 B]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-zope.component all 4.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3 [43.1 kB]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-certbot all 0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [208 kB]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 certbot all 0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [11.0 kB]
Get:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-augeas all 0.5.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [9,288 B]
Get:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-certbot-apache all 0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [69.7 kB]
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-certbot-apache all 0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1 [3,964 B]
Fetched 1,654 kB in 4s (422 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package augeas-lenses.
(Reading database ... 173513 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-augeas-lenses_1.10.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking augeas-lenses (1.10.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-josepy.
Preparing to unpack .../01-python3-josepy_1.1.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-josepy (1.1.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pbr.
Preparing to unpack .../02-python3-pbr_3.1.1-3ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pbr (3.1.1-3ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-mock.
Preparing to unpack .../03-python3-mock_2.0.0-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-mock (2.0.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-requests-toolbelt.
Preparing to unpack .../04-python3-requests-toolbelt_0.8.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-requests-toolbelt (0.8.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-tz.
Preparing to unpack .../05-python3-tz_2018.3-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tz (2018.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-rfc3339.
Preparing to unpack .../06-python3-rfc3339_1.0-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-rfc3339 (1.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-acme.
Preparing to unpack .../07-python3-acme_0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-acme (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-ndg-httpsclient.
Preparing to unpack .../08-python3-ndg-httpsclient_0.4.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-ndg-httpsclient (0.4.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-configargparse.
Preparing to unpack .../09-python3-configargparse_0.11.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-configargparse (0.11.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-future.
Preparing to unpack .../10-python3-future_0.15.2-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-future (0.15.2-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-parsedatetime.
Preparing to unpack .../11-python3-parsedatetime_2.4-3+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-parsedatetime (2.4-3+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-zope.hookable.
Preparing to unpack .../12-python3-zope.hookable_4.0.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-zope.hookable (4.0.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-zope.event.
Preparing to unpack .../13-python3-zope.event_4.2.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-zope.event (4.2.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-zope.component.
Preparing to unpack .../14-python3-zope.component_4.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-zope.component (4.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-certbot.
Preparing to unpack .../15-python3-certbot_0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-certbot (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package certbot.
Preparing to unpack .../16-certbot_0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking certbot (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaugeas0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libaugeas0_1.10.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaugeas0:amd64 (1.10.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-augeas.
Preparing to unpack .../18-python3-augeas_0.5.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-augeas (0.5.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-certbot-apache.
Preparing to unpack .../19-python3-certbot-apache_0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-certbot-apache (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-certbot-apache.
Preparing to unpack .../20-python-certbot-apache_0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-certbot-apache (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-icu.
Preparing to unpack .../21-python3-icu_1.9.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-icu (1.9.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-requests-toolbelt (0.8.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python3-pbr (3.1.1-3ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3-pbr to provide /usr/bin/pbr (pbr) in auto mode
Setting up python3-mock (2.0.0-3) ...
Setting up python3-zope.event (4.2.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-icu (1.9.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-configargparse (0.11.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-zope.hookable (4.0.4-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python3-future (0.15.2-4+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3-futurize to provide /usr/bin/futurize (futurize) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize to provide /usr/bin/pasteurize (pasteurize) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up augeas-lenses (1.10.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-ndg-httpsclient (0.4.4-1) ...
Setting up python3-josepy (1.1.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python3-tz (2018.3-2) ...
Setting up python3-parsedatetime (2.4-3+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
Setting up python3-rfc3339 (1.0-4) ...
Setting up python3-zope.component (4.3.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3) ...
Setting up libaugeas0:amd64 (1.10.1-2) ...
Setting up python3-augeas (0.5.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python3-acme (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python3-certbot (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up certbot (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/certbot.timer → /lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer.
certbot.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up python3-certbot-apache (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python-certbot-apache (0.31.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
root@jaimemontoya:~#
```

Obtain a certificate that covers jaimemontoya.com:

```
root@jaimemontoya:~# certbot --apache -d jaimemontoya.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Enter email address (used for urgent renewal and security notices) (Enter 'c' to
cancel): webmaster@jaimemontoya.com

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Please read the Terms of Service at
https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf. You must
agree in order to register with the ACME server at
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(A)gree/(C)ancel: A

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Would you be willing to share your email address with the Electronic Frontier
Foundation, a founding partner of the Let's Encrypt project and the non-profit
organization that develops Certbot? We'd like to send you email about our work
encrypting the web, EFF news, campaigns, and ways to support digital freedom.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o: Y
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for jaimemontoya.com
Enabled Apache rewrite module
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Created an SSL vhost at /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf
Enabled Apache socache_shmcb module
Enabled Apache ssl module
Deploying Certificate to VirtualHost /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf
Enabling available site: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf

Please choose whether or not to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, removing HTTP access.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: No redirect - Make no further changes to the webserver configuration.
2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access. Choose this for
new sites, or if you're confident your site works on HTTPS. You can undo this
change by editing your web server's configuration.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Enabled Apache rewrite module
Redirecting vhost in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to ssl vhost in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Congratulations! You have successfully enabled https://jaimemontoya.com

You should test your configuration at:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jaimemontoya.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/jaimemontoya.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/jaimemontoya.com/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2019-09-16. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again
   with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew *all* of
   your certificates, run "certbot renew"
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF: https://eff.org/donate-le
```

In order to redirect www URLs to non-www, go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and add this line: `Redirect permanent / https://jaimemontoya.com/`. The content of that file now is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/books

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jaimemontoya.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Redirect permanent / https://jaimemontoya.com/
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Finally, restart the server:

```
root@jaimemontoya:~# service apache2 restart
```

Reference: https://jaimemontoya.com/securing-php-apps/#20190618124343